# Search through an email to find and highlight text

Tags: vba, email, excel, outlook

I'm working with Excel's VBA trying to automate the sending of some emails. Right now, the code creates an email based on the cells next to the button clicked, forwards the email to the listed in a cell, and then inserts a specific body message based on some more cells. What is in the cells isn't really important, but what I need to do is search the original forwarded message for specific text, and if found, it needs to highlight that text.

My code is as follows:

```
Sub Asset_email()
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNs As Namespace
Dim Fldr As MAPIFolder
Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim i As Integer
Dim olMsg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim r As Range
Dim strLocation As String
Dim o As Outlook.Application
Dim strbody As String

'Dim olAtt As Outlook.Attachments
'Set olAtt = olMsg.Attachments

Set r = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell
Range(Cells(r.Row, r.Column), Cells(r.Row, r.Column)).Select

Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Fldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Asset Notifications Macro")
i = 1


For Each olMail In Fldr.Items
If InStr(olMail.body, ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, ColumnOffset:=-3).Value) <> 0 Then
olMail.display



    strbody = "<BODY style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri>Team,<br><br>" & _
              "Please see the notice below regarding " & _
              ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, ColumnOffset:=-2).Value & _
              ".<br><br> Feel free to email the CSG team at myemailhere@email.com with any questions.<br><br>" & _
                "Thank you!"

With olMail.Forward
.To = ActiveCell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=-1)
.display
SendKeys ("%")
SendKeys ("7")
 'Call Sleep
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
.HTMLBody = strbody & "<br>" & .HTMLBody

End With
End If
Next
End Sub
```

The code works 100%. I just don't know the correct syntax to search and highlight the results.

In the above example, lets say I wanted to find and highlight the words "Thank you". How would one go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
.HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "Thank you", "<FONT style=" & Chr(34) & "BACKGROUND-COLOR: yellow" & Chr(34) & ">" & "Thank you" & "</FONT>")
```

Answer (score 1):

You basically have to use the Word Object Model for the text searching and highlighting.  There's a perfect example of how to do it in this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg193974.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link! That seems to be instructions on how to highlight with XML and C#. I'm not sure how to convert that to VBA

Comment: Just focus on the Word objects and properties that are used and you can do the same thing in VBA

Answer (score 1):

Highlight in the active Inspector? Try the following.

You can substitute the line `set objInspector = Application.ActiveInspector` with `set objInspector = olMail.GetInspector`

```
 wdColorYellow = 65535
 set objInspector = Application.ActiveInspector
 set objDoc = objInspector.WordEditor
 set objFind = objDoc.Content.Find
 objFind.HitHighlight "text_to_highlight", wdColorYellow, , false, true
```

Comment: Thanks! How should I dim the objInspector though? I'm getting an error that the object variable isn't set

Comment: @JGoldz75 `Dim objInspector As Outlook.Inspector`

Comment: Or you can declare the variables as a generic Object to avoid having to reference the Outlook and Word type libraries.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model provides three main ways for working item bodies:

1. [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx) -  a string representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item.
2. [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx) - a string representing the HTML body of the specified item. In that case you need to parse the HTML markup and add surrounding tags for highlighting the text. For example, you may use the `<b>` for bold symbols.
3. [Word editor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) - the Microsoft Word Document Object Model of the message being displayed. The WordEditor property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Document class from the Word object model which you can use to work on the message body. The [Bold](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822177(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Font class allows to format the text as bold.

You can read more about all these ways in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx). It us up to you which way (HTML or Word object model) is to choose for highlighting the text.

Comment: I've read this over and I'm afraid it's a little over my skill level. The text I am trying to search for will appear twice, once in the body of the message created when I forward the email, and once in the original forwarded email. Not sure if that would make one of these options better than the other. I'm also not sure how to modify my code to efficiently include one of these methods. I hate to sound like a lazy poster, but do you think you could guide me through this using the code I have currently? I'm very interested in learning how to do this type of stuff.

Comment: I'd suggest starting from the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736(v=office.14).aspx) article in that case.