# Find string in htmlbody and modify font

Tags: vba, outlook

**Background:**

Where an email has actions associated we indicate the name of the responsible party.  To make it easier to skim and see your actions, I want to add colors to a name, e.g., PersonA = blue & PersonB = red.

---

**Issue:**

Macro recording doesn't seem to work when drafting an email, so I'm attempting to use Excel knowledge to generate the code.  I appear to have an issue with the Range/Selection portion when attempting to `Range.Find()` within Outlook.  I get `RTE 438, Object doesn't support this property or method` on the `with .find()` line.  Having attempted to use `oRng = oWrdApp.HTMLBody`, I get the same error, but on the `Set oRng` line.

---

**Inquiry:**

How do you search for a string within the HTMLBody of your active-draft email then modify that string, for each instance of `Find()`?

---

**Attempted code:**

```
Private Sub color_names() 'IN PROGRESS
    Dim nameOptions As Variant:  nameOptions = Array("PersonA", "PersonB")
    Dim NewMail As MailItem, oInspector As Inspector
    Set oInspector = Application.ActiveInspector
    Dim oDoc As Object, oWrdApp As Object, oSelection As Object
    Set oDoc = oInspector.WordEditor
    Set oWrdApp = oDoc.Application
    Set oSelection = oWrdApp.Selection
    Dim trueName As Variant:  For Each trueName In nameOptions
        Dim oRng As Variant:  Set oRng = oSelection.Range
        With oRng
            Select Case True
                Case IsError(.Find(trueName))
                Case Else
                    With .Find(nameOptions(trueName))
                        'Expecting to set an array up for RGB related to each person
                        .Font.Color = RGB(255, 165, 0) 
                        .Font.Bold = True
                    End With
            End Select
        End With
    Next trueName
    Set oSelection = Nothing
    Set oWrdApp = Nothing
    Set oDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You could try a `Replace`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30875365/search-through-an-email-to-find-and-highlight-text

Comment: You could try this if you figure out the Outlook equivalent of `ActiveDocument`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72425926/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-specific-words. You could add the msword tag.